# Pagination with Codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have a problem with my codeigniter app. I have setup a controller method like so:

```
    public function program_search()
    {
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/site/program_search/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('wc_program')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 15;
    $config['num_links'] = 1;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $config['num_links'] = 1;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination pagination-small"><ul>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo;';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] =  '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $term = $this->input->post('term');

    $this->db->like('JobRef', $term);
    $this->db->or_like('Area', $term);
    $this->db->or_like('Parish', $term);
    $this->db->or_like('WorkType', $term);
    $this->db->or_like('Location', $term);
    $this->db->order_by('wc_program.JobRef');
    $this->db->limit(15, $this->uri->segment(3));  
    $q = $this->db->get('wc_program');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data['results'] = $q->result();    
    }    
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();        
    $this->front->set('title', 'Search our current programmes');
    $this->front->set('metadesc', 'Program Search');
    $this->front->set('metakeywords', '');
    $this->front->buffer('content', 'site/program_search_results', $data);
    $this->front->render();
    }
```

But it shows the results based on what is typed in the search box, but yet if theres less then 15 results it still shows the pagination, which i don't want. If the results are more than 15 then again the pagination is displayed which i do want but then going to the next page there's nothing there, from the code can someone tell me what i have done wrong please ?

I'm really stuck as what is wrong and need some help on this please...

Thanks in adavnce

Comment: You need to pass in the total rows of your result, not the total rows of a fetch all from the table. Do you search first and pass in the total rows of that result.

Comment: Ok so how would i do that based on the code already there then?

Comment: I'll add an answer give me a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this

```
$this->db->like('JobRef', $term);
$this->db->or_like('Area', $term);
$this->db->or_like('Parish', $term);
$this->db->or_like('WorkType', $term);
$this->db->or_like('Location', $term);
$this->db->order_by('wc_program.JobRef');
$this->db->limit(15, $this->uri->segment(3));  
$q = $this->db->get('wc_program');
if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
    $data['results'] = $q->result();    
}
```

Above your pagination config, so that you can pass

```
$q->num_rows()
```

to the `$config['total_rows']` parameter..

```
public function program_search()
{
    $term = $this->input->post('term');

    // records for pagination, without a limit
    $this->db->like('JobRef', $term);
    $this->db->or_like('Area', $term);
    $this->db->or_like('Parish', $term);
    $this->db->or_like('WorkType', $term);
    $this->db->or_like('Location', $term);
    $this->db->order_by('wc_program.JobRef');  
    $q = $this->db->get('wc_program');

    // records for displaying, with a limit
    $this->db->like('JobRef', $term);
    $this->db->or_like('Area', $term);
    $this->db->or_like('Parish', $term);
    $this->db->or_like('WorkType', $term);
    $this->db->or_like('Location', $term);
    $this->db->order_by('wc_program.JobRef');
    $this->db->limit(15, $this->uri->segment(3));  
    $query = $this->db->get('wc_program');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data['results'] = $query->result();    
    }

    // pagination
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/site/program_search/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $q->num_rows(); // new pagination setting, using the unlimited results
    $config['per_page'] = 15;
    $config['num_links'] = 1;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $config['num_links'] = 1;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination pagination-small"><ul>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo;';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] =  '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();        
    $this->front->set('title', 'Search our current programmes');
    $this->front->set('metadesc', 'Program Search');
    $this->front->set('metakeywords', '');
    $this->front->buffer('content', 'site/program_search_results', $data);
    $this->front->render();
}
```

You may need to tweak the offset parameter too, I can't test this code locally but it should get you started.

Comment: LEGEND!But one small thing now, the pagination doesn't show if more than 15 results are returned which obviously it needs to do so the user can see more results, but anything less than 15 dont show the pagination.

Comment: I still need some help on this please someone!

Comment: The problem is the `limit()` part of the query. You can't add the limit, because `num_rows()` will always be 15 or less. You essentially need to run the query twice -- the first time with no LIMIT clause (to see how many *total* rows there are), and the second time with the limit/offset to retrieve that specific page.

Comment: @cryode is absolutely right, you need to get the number of the results without a limit claus, and then perform the query with a limit. I shouldn't of answered this so late at night!

Comment: Right ok, i just commented out the line

     $this->db->limit(15, $this->uri->segment(3));

And it kinda worked but when more than 15 results and i goto page 2 it shows nothing !

Comment: I'll update my answer.. Sorry about this I answered this very late last night and shouldn't have :)

Comment: @the_unforgiven_II I've updated my answer, there may be better ways to reuse the query built by codeigniter, might be worth scanning the docs for that. By the way.. Is your name a Metallica song? if so hi5 o/

Comment: @Dale yes Metallica best band ever!

The update you just did still doesn't show anything on the next page :(

Comment: @the_unforgiven_II I've tried to invite you to chat but it's not letting me.. If you view my profile, you can visit my site, and from there, you can send me an email. I'll gladly help out but I need more information, probably more than is welcome here as the question will become so localized it will be closed. Feel free to email me from the site and I'll get back to as soon as I can.

Comment: @Dale sent you an email buddy

Answer (score 0):

You can use $config['total_rows'] and ask if there are more than 15, if yes display pagination links

```
if($config['total_rows']>15):
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
endif;
```

Comment: that doesn't do it either pagination not showing and when it does it's showing the remaining results either.

Comment: If the total rows is less than one page, the pagination library won't output anything. This `if` check is pointless.